# Preventing open redirects / xss on a variable return url / iframe

Tags: url-redirection, reflected-xss

Let's assume I have a website where I have to either redirect the user to another URL or include another URL in an iframe, that is given by a GET parameter.
I cannot use HMAC when the URL is created. The site is designed to work with relative URLs.

e.g. `login.php?redirect=profile.php`

This is vulnerable to open redirect (`login.php?redirect=//evil.com/change_password_form.php`) and XSS (`login.php?redirect=javascript:alert('evil')`) if not protected.

Allowing absolute URLs is not a problem, these are easy to allow by a list.

To check relative URLs and XSS is harder...

Would it be enough to:

1. remove white-spaces and non-printable characters or deny if these exist
2. deny if starts with `//`
3. deny if contains `:` NOT preceded by `?`, `/` or `#`

#3 would prevent switching the scheme, #2 would prevent going to another origin.

Other approaches suggest using a Lib for URL parsing (but these fail too) or using CSP (but that is something that should be used in addition and not as the only defense).

When using an URL parser, is it enough to:

1. remove white-spaces and non-printable characters or deny if these exist
2. deny if parsed scheme/protocol is not empty
3. deny if parsed host/hostname/domain/authority (some parser have a lot of fields here) is not empty
4. deny if parser has an error

Since parsing URLs is hard I'm 100% sure I missed something. What would you do?